# CPU usage way too high in Task Manager

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage, task-manager, bitlocker, windows-defender

One service is taking a LOT of CPU usage, and it doesn't cool down.

[image: High CPU usage Windows 10]

This started when I enabled some Windows features (Application Guard, Guarded Host, etc), and turned on BitLocker on my main C: drive.

Comment: The "Microsoft Compatibility Telemetry" process usually appears after Windows updates and program installations, and takes longer to complete the more you have installed. The other process at the top though has a logo of a svchost process... If you run [Process Hacker](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/) as an administrator, you should be able to see which process is taking up that amount of CPU.

Answer (score 0):

"Microsoft Compatibility Telemetry" eats your system, which I saw in the image which you shared.

That process is built-in software of Windows 10 like cmd.exe or svchost.exe.

So, what is "Telemetry"?

"Telemetry" is a kind of software which collects data about user's computer usage.

So even if you remove it, it will come back.

I heard that there are softwares which claim disabling annoying Windows 10 features like that.

For example:

https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10

You can try it; but ***Own your risk!***; because I did not try it.

Or you can downgrade your OS to 7 or 8.1.